# Incorporating third-party design into web or mobile app

Tags: html, css, meteor

I am building a prototype of a financial visualization app, using Meteor.  I have zero experience in programming, the extent of my knowledge is what I have taught myself in HTML, CSS, JS and Meteor over the last year.  I have a solid working prototype, enough to showcase the benefits of the app and am continuing to add more features.

At some point, I will either find a technical partner (with equity) or find funding to hire a developer.  In the meantime, various people have recommended that I spend some money ($500-$1,000) to hire a designer and give the app a better look.  I am open to this but my questions are:

- how would I incorporate this design work into my app?  Would they work directly in my code?  Or would they provide me with mockups that I would then need to somehow replicate in my HTML/CSS?

I would love to make improvements to the app, especially if I am seeking funding, as I will quickly approach the limits of my programming knowledge (this is a side project).  I'm missing a step as to how I would do this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the designer will create a wireframe for you.  Basically a fully designed page with hard-coded dummy data.  Then you can take their code and replace the dummy data with live data.

Make sure you use version control for this step.  You want to make sure you can revert to your version in case something doesn't end up working correctly.

There are pre-made templates and themes for websites that can be free or cost as little as $100.  You don't get a personalized touch, but they can make things look presentable if you don't want to break the bank for a designer.

Comment: Thanks. Would they provide the wireframe as a PhotoShop file or directly in HTML?  Or my choice?

Comment: I've worked with designers that provide html.  But I'm sure they can provide whatever you want.